# why does ajax call expecting type json not capture message in HttpStatusCodeResult in production but works fine in Staging?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an application where the ASP.NET 4.6 Web API returns `HttpStatusCodeResult` object in case of an error and returns a JSON object on success:

```
public class CertificationController : Controller
{
   public async Task<ActionResult> GetImagesAsync(string certFilter)
   {
       try
       {
          int imageCount = GetImagesCount(certFilter);

          if (imageCount == 0)
          {
             return new HttpStatusCodeResult(404, "No images to download");
          }
          else if (imageCount > 100)
          {
             return new HttpStatusCodeResult(400, "Cannot download more than 100 images");
          } 
          else
          {
             string PathToImageZipfile = ZipImages(certFilter);
             return Json(new{zipfile=PathToImageZipfile});
          }
       }
       catch(Exception e)
       {
           return new HttpStatusCodeResult(400, "Failed to download images");
       }
   }
}
```

The above API method is called in the frontend using Ajax:

```
getImages(filtercert: string): any {
    notifierInstance.setNotifier(true, appConst.LoadingText);

    var certDataFilter = ko.toJSON(filtercert);

    return $.ajax({
        url: "/certificate/getImagesAsync",
        data: '{"certfilter":' + certDataFilter + '}',
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        async: true,
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {

            notifierInstance.setNotifier(true, appConst.downloadWaiting);
        },
        success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
            window.open(data);
            notifierInstance.setNotifierSelfHide(appConst.downloadWaiting);
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            if (xhr.status == 400) {
                notifierInstance.setNotifierErrorSelfHideLongWait(error);
            }
            else if (xhr.status == 404) {
                notifierInstance.setNotifierWarningSelfHideLongWait(error);
            }
            else {
                notifierInstance.setNotifierError(appConst.ErrorLoadingText);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The ajax call is able to read the custom message inside `HttpStatusCodeResult` object in staging & lower environments. But in Production, the ajax call is unable to read the custom message inside the `HttpStatusCodeResult` object.

I understand that because ajax is expecting a JSON type object, the ajax call fails to read the custom message in `HttpStatusCodeResult`. However the issue is only happening in Production and I have to recreate this issue in the lower environment to convince my supervisor that the API code cannot return `HttpStatusCodeResult` to an ajax call that is expecting a response of type JSON.

How can I recreate this production issue in Dev/QA/Staging environment?

I tried deploying in Dev environment, the production code with the connection strings pointing to the dev database. The code worked without any error in the Dev environment

Comment: What specifically is failing?  In your browser's debugging tools, are there any errors on the browser console?  On the network tab of those tools, is the AJAX request made?  What is the server's response?  In the script debugger of those tools, what specifically happens when you debug?

Comment: the message in HttpStatusCodeResult objects is used by the frontend script to display in the notifiers. Since the message is never received at the ajax call's error handling when a 400/404 error is returned, the notifier is display with no message. It like an empty alert window. The http response only returns the status code (400/404) and status text like "Bad Request"/"Not Found".

I was thinking is there someway a firewall or IIS setting in the production server could prevent the message in HttpStatusCodeResult from being transmitted to the frontend  when the API is called ?